# Text Index Creation for MongoDB INVALID UTF-8

Tags: mongodb

I get this error, I've found 3 at most posts about it and every one has a really vague answer to it that doesn't help me in the slightest.

I /need/ to fix all invalid data without reimporting OR skip the data with invalid utf-8. I cant find anything that tells me how to do this.

I'd love a reply thank you.

```
> db.data.createIndex({username: "text"})
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "text contains invalid UTF-8",
        "code" : 28755,
        "codeName" : "Location28755"
}
>
```